# woocommerce function to create product programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, programmatically-created

I need to create a product manually from php script
(e.g. i'm developing a custom front-end form to insert products)

Googling i see some support forum create manually a post (using wp_insert_post function).
I think this solution is not reliable (with a woocommerce update things may changes).

I need a wc function that does it for me, a sort of wc_create_product (like wc_create_order function).

I've found `WC_API_Products::create_product()` seems to be what i need but on the web i could not find any additional documentation or usage example except the code comment. 
Additionally this function is not listed on woocommerce official api doc at https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/.

I need to know if this function is thought for internal use or maybe for external developer like me.

Does anyone have some information about it?

thanks

Comment: It is in the [REST API docs](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product)

Comment: Thanks, you are right! So i guess the function it is only usable within REST protocol... So my question persist: is there a function to create product in a font-end form?? i don't know why all post type have their crete function except wc-product..

Comment: No other post types have specific creation functions. Any/all post types can be created via [`wp_insert_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Answer (score 4):

In Woocommerce, products are represented by objects of the class `WC_Product` which is documented [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html).

The documentation dicourages us from using the constructor explicitly, however, this works. We can create products by calling the constructor and then add properties.

```
$product = new WC_Product();
$product->set_name('My Product')
...
```